# Run a MySQL query when a link get pressed

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP code that creates a table from my query. In this table, I would like to create links based on the output (path). When clicked on these, they would trigger another query to run. See my code and further explanation below.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "DB1");

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM testDB";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>file</th>";
                echo "<th>path</th>";
                echo "<th>type</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['file'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['path'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

So when running this I get a table with output containing file, path, type. What I would like to do now is to make path as a link in the table and when clicked, this query should execute giving a new table: `SELECT * FROM testDB WHERE path = 'PATH FROM THE LINK'.`

I have tried to implement this by using prepared statements, changing my code to:

```
if (isset($_GET["path"])) {
    $sql1 = "SELECT `file`, `path`, `type` FROM testDB WHERE path=?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_GET["path"]);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM testDB";
    $result = $link->query($sql);
}
if ($result) {
    if ($result->num_rows) {
```

and then in the table add:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://myurl.com/test.php?path=" . $row['path'] . "'>" . $row['path'] . "<a/></td>";
```

but clicking the link, which should execute `SELECT file, path, type FROM testDB WHERE path=?` always give "No records matching your query were found." What could be the problem? Also, please be aware that I am having backslashes in path, but this is getting escaped thanks to the prepared statement, right? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try to use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_num_rows.

Answer (score 0):

try using step by step

```
 $stmt->execute();
 $result = $stmt->fetch(); // or fetchAll for multiple arrays
 $connection = null;
```

m getting using this so try it...

Comment: `bindParam` is PDO, `bind_param` is mysqli. They're using `mysqli` so that is correct (`$link = mysqli_connect(`). http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php vs. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: oop's thanks,  but m getting output using PDO @chris85

Comment: `bindParam` is PDO so it will work with it. `bind_param` won't work with `PDO`... and vice versa.